# How do I return multiple rows of parameter data with C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

I'm using C# to extract data to T-SQL parameters, the query is:

```
DECLARE @Param1 INT, @Param2 NCHAR(50), @P3 REAL, @P4 BIT
SELECT @Param1 = [idx]
      ,@Param2 = [data]
      ,@P3 = [itgetsreal]
      ,@P4 = [wazzup]
    FROM [T].[dbo].[temp];
```

Running from MS SQL Server Management Studio yields a predictable one line dataset, the last.  My C# code creates output parameters:

```
public class ParamData 
{   //  query has executed, return parameter data in class properties
    public string[] names; public Object[] vals; public bool success = false;
    public ParamData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd == null) {
            err = "SqlCommand \"cmd\" may not be NULL";
            errcode = -1; errdata = ""; errsrc = "ParamData(SqlCommand cmd)"; }
        else {
            if (cmd.Parameters == null) { err = "\"SqlCommand.Parameters\" may not be NULL";
                errcode = -1; errdata = cmd.CommandText; errsrc = "ParamData(SqlCommand cmd)"; }
            else { 
                try {err = ""; errcode = 0; errdata = ""; errsrc = ""; 
                    int cnt = cmd.Parameters.Count;
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        names = new string[cnt]; vals = new object[cnt];
                        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                        {
                            names[i] = cmd.Parameters[i].ParameterName;
                            vals[i] = cmd.Parameters[i].Value;
                        }
                    }
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex) {
                    err = ex.Message; errcode = ex.Number;
                    errdata    = String.Format("Parameters name/val assignment: Query: \"{0}\"",
                                                    cmd.CommandText);
                    errsrc     = "ParamData(SqlCommand cmd)";} 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I create a SqlReader type object where I can extract each row of the dataset and not only the last?

BTW:  I've got means already to bring in the data without parameters but am constrained to provide a legacy compatibility and can't yet replicate the original function.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking here, your SQL will only every return 1 row. If your statement were to return multiple rows, then your C# code would automatically handle that. For your c# to get a dataset with multiple rows, you need a statement that returns multiple rows. If the statement you're running isn't the statement in your question, then show us the SQL you are *actually* running.

Comment: How is your `ParamData` class supposed to handle multiple sets of parameters? Or will you try to create a `ParamData` object for each of the results? As is, your current approach wouldn't be able to neither retrieve nor provide a collection of results

Comment: From your description it's probably worth pointing out that a `@variable` holds a single scalar value - it's not an array, set, list, dictionary, object etc. If you run a query that returns a recordset and assign a column to a variable, the variable will (typically) contain the value from the last row - and *only* that. If you want to consume multiple rows just return a recordset, remove the variables.

Comment: As @Stu mentioned, your SQL query will only return one row. If you want multiple rows that C# can then process, your SQL statement simply needs to select from the table like ```SELECT [idx],[data],[itgetsreal],[wazzup] FROM [T].[dbo].[temp];```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the result set, but you can also return 'Full Result Set' into a SSIS user variable with type Object (and then deal with the results in an SSIS loop, or in c#).

Comment: @Larnu you are correct, though I don't include that last query line in what I pass in to SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection)

Comment: @JoshPart, you hit the nail on the head, how do I?  I created a SqlDataReader in the calling program but get False for SqlDataReader.Read()

Comment: @Stu, you're correct and I've done that already, I'm merely trying to provide legacy compatibility.  Is everyone saying I can only receive one "row" of parameter data?  That my reading the class documentation for SqlParameterCollection is correct, that we can't get a full resultset?  What about the asynch SqlReader, same thing?

Comment: You're aware that there are ways to return many rows, but the thing here is: you say this is all about legacy compatibility, and if I understand correctly, this "legacy" system expects an array of values and works with an array of values. There MIGHT be a workaround to return a full resultset using your current approach, but we need to know how this legacy system works and what does it expect from your function/ParamData object to actually be able to provide a fully functional solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple rows of T-SQL variables/parameters.  Parameters only hold the last value.

The comments are spot on - one needs to return datasets (*not through parameters*) to obtain multiple rows.